# Let $U=2X$ and $V=-3Y$. Find Correlation (U,V) given Correlation $(X,Y)=0.8$.

Tags: statistics, correlation, covariance

Let $U=2X$ and $V=-3Y$. Find Correlation (U,V) given Correlation $(X,Y)=0.8$.

My Steps:

$$\begin{align}
Correlation (U,V) & = \dfrac{Cov(U,V)}{\sqrt{Var(U)\cdot Var(V)}} \\
 & = \dfrac{Cov(2X,-3Y)}{\sqrt{Var(2X)\cdot Var(-3Y)}} \\ 
 & = \dfrac{(-6)Cov(X,Y)}{\sqrt{4Var(X)\cdot 9Var(Y)}} \\
 & = \dfrac{(-6)Cov(X,Y)}{6\sqrt{Var(X)\cdot Var(Y)}} \\
 & = \dfrac{-Cov(X,Y)}{\sqrt{Var(X)\cdot Var(Y)}} \\
 & = -0.8 \\
\end{align}$$

Have I done this correctly ?

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Comment: Hence, more generally, $\text{Corr}(aX,bY)=$ $____$ $\text{Corr}(X,Y)$.